# Center text vertically inside label

Tags: java, layout, swt

Is it possible to center the text inside a label vertically? I'm using:

```
message1 = new Label(shell, SWT.VERTICAL | SWT.CENTER);
```

This centers the text horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: Why not center the label vertically within its parent?

Answer (score 2):

```
CLabel label = new CLabel(shell, SWT.CENTER);
```

Maybe you should try using `org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel` ([JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCLabel.html)).
The code above exactly centers the text in the label vertically.

Answer (score 1):

The text within a label is always aligned at the top. The `VERTICAL` style only applies when `SEPARATOR` is set. In this case it displays a single vertical or horizontal line and the text is ignored.

But you can center the label itself within the parent. For example, this snippet centers a label within the containing shell by using a `GridLayout`:

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell parent = new Shell( display );
  Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( "some text" );
  label.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_GREEN ) );

  parent.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
  label.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true ) );

  parent.open();
  while( !parent.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @Baz Thanks for the hint, I've updated the answer accordingly.